# App crashes when deleting item from ListView on delete button click

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, notifydatasetchanged

I'm having a really hard time getting around an issue with my code.

When pressing the delete button in a ListView item, ideally the item should be removed and the list view should be refreshed when calling notifyDataSetChanged();

This is however not the case, calling this method after removing an item from the underlying ArrayList that populates the ListView, causing the app to crash.

Also, the above mentioned ArrayList, being the source of the data, exists in an Activity which extends Application, allowing global access to the data source through out the app.

Below is my code. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
public class CartListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Product> {

    private ArrayList<Product> products;

    //Application context where ArrayList exists for globabal access
    final Global globalVariables = (Global) getContext().getApplicationContext();


    public CartListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Product> products ) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, products);

        this.products=products;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View row = convertView;
        prodHolder mainHolder;
         final int pos=position;
        if(row == null)
        {

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_cart_row_item, parent, false);
//create holders for listview items
        final prodHolder holder = new prodHolder();
            holder.txtName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.cart_product_name);
            holder.txtAmount= (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.cart_product_price);
            holder.txtQuantity=(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.cart_quantity_text);
            holder.txtRestaurant= (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.cart_restaurant);
            holder.txtType = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.cart_type);
            holder.txtOption  = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.cart_option);
            holder.plus = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.cart_increment_quantity);
            holder.minus = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.cart_decrement_quantity);
            holder.delete = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.cart_delete_button);

            holder.delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                   globalVariables.getGlobalProductArrayList().remove(position);
                    CartListAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }
            });
//when clicking the plus button in the cart on an item, the cart changes accordingly
            holder.plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //change quantity when increment button pressed
                    String quantityTextValue= (String) holder.txtQuantity.getText();
                    int quantityConvertedInt = Integer.parseInt(quantityTextValue);
                    int newQuantity= quantityConvertedInt+1;
                    holder.txtQuantity.setText(newQuantity+"");
                    //change total amount when increment button pressed
                    String amountTextValue = (String) holder.txtAmount.getText();
                    int  amountConvertedInt = Integer.parseInt(amountTextValue);
                    int pricePerItem = amountConvertedInt/quantityConvertedInt;
                    int newPrice = amountConvertedInt+pricePerItem;
                    holder.txtAmount.setText(newPrice+"");

                    //get textviews from holders
                    Product product = new Product("", 0, 0, "", "", "");

                    String name = (String) holder.txtName.getText();
                    String price = (String) holder.txtAmount.getText();
                    String quantity = (String) holder.txtQuantity.getText();
                    String restaurant = (String) holder.txtRestaurant.getText();
                    String mealType = (String) holder.txtType.getText();
                    String option = (String) holder.txtOption.getText();
                    //set attributes of temporary product
                    product.setProductName(name);
                    product.setProductPrice(Integer.parseInt(price));
                    product.setProductQuantity(Integer.parseInt(quantity));
                    product.setRestaurant(restaurant);
                    product.setProductType(mealType);
                    product.setProductOption(option);

                    int cartLength = globalVariables.getMyProductsSize();

                    //loop through arraylist that exists in global context
                    for ( int i = 0; i < cartLength; i++) {
                        Product p = globalVariables.getMyProducts(i);

                        //if temporary product attributes match the attributes of product in arraylist

                        if (product.getProductName().equals(p.getProductName())
                                && product.getProductType().equals(p.getProductType())
                                && product.getProductOption().equals(p.getProductOption()))
                        //update that products attributes with the new quantity and total price so
                        // that listview does not refresh values
                        {
                            p.setProductQuantity(product.getProductQuantity());
                            p.setProductPrice(product.getProductPrice());
                        }

                    }

                }
            });


            row.setTag(holder);

        }

        mainHolder = (prodHolder) row.getTag();


        //get product stored in array that exists in Application class
        Product p = globalVariables.getMyProducts(position);


        mainHolder.txtName.setText(p.getProductName());
        mainHolder.txtAmount.setText(p.getProductPrice()+"");
        mainHolder.txtQuantity.setText(p.getProductQuantity()+"");
        mainHolder.txtRestaurant.setText(p.getRestaurant());
        mainHolder.txtType.setText(p.getProductType());
        mainHolder.txtOption.setText(p.getProductOption());

        return row;

    }

}
```

And Global class that extends ArrayList...

```
public class Global extends Application {


    //holds an array of products throughout application life cycle
    private ArrayList <Product> myProducts = new ArrayList<>();
    //not in use
    private Cart cart;


    public Cart getCart() {

        return cart;
    }

    public void setCart(Cart cart) {

        this.cart = cart;
    }


    public ArrayList <Product> getGlobalProductArrayList(){

        return this.myProducts;
    }

    public void removeItem (int position){

        myProducts.remove(position);
    }


//gets the products in the arraylist at the specified position
    public Product getMyProducts(int position) {
        return myProducts.get(position);
    }
//adds a product to the array
    public void addMyProducts(Product product) {
        myProducts.add(product);
    }
//get the size of the array, the amount of products in an array
    public int getMyProductsSize (){
        return myProducts.size();
    }

}
```

Stacktrace...

```
01-29 23:40:13.992 28953-28953/za.co.clickandeat.clickeatbeta W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x415c0d88)
01-29 23:40:13.992 28953-28953/za.co.clickandeat.clickeatbeta E/test: Exception
01-29 23:40:14.032 28953-28953/za.co.clickandeat.clickeatbeta E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
Process: za.co.clickandeat.clickeatbeta, PID: 28953   java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1
at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255) 
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
at za.co.clickandeat.clickeatbeta.Global.getMyProducts(Global.java:43) 
at za.co.clickandeat.clickeatbeta.CartListAdapter.getView(CartListAdapter.java:147)    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2240) 
at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1263)  
at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1175)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16643)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)   
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16643)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125) 
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16643)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16643)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16643)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16643)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125) 
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16643)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2298)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16643)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1916)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1113)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1295)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5675)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5214)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:814)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:630)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Are you sure you're adding to your Global class's list and not just your adapter's?

Comment: Adding? Can you be more specific?

Comment: The error is thrown at Global.getMyProducts(Global.java:43), trying to call get(1) when there is only 1 item in your list. In your adapter, you're calling globalVariables.getMyProducts(position);, where you updated the Global data, but not the data your Adapter actually references, so the two Lists are out of alignment, causing the IndexOutOfBoundsException. Changing globalVariables.getMyProducts(position); to products.get(position); will solve the Exception, but you need to ensure your delete call also removes the item from the List backed by your Adapter

Comment: This suggestion worked somewhat. The app no longer crashes and the list view refreshes. However, now when I delete an item from both the lists , if there are more than 3 items, deleting the most last item on the list, deletes the first item inside the list view instead.

Comment: That's because the list your adapter is backed by is out of sync with the single instance stored in your Application class, which is what I'm trying to explain.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably call remove() method on the array adapter. The parameter is Product object that you want to remove.

```
Product product = globalVariables.getGlobalProductArrayList().get(position);
adapter.remove(product);
```

Doing remove like this ensures that the adapter knows about the deleted item and it notifies itself that something has changed thereby updating all the properties of the adapter.